# specified in Branch dashboard doesn't match with the deep link intent in manifest file

Tags: android, url-scheme, branch.io

I have this scheme **testapp** in my manifest as below

```
     <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="testapp" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and same i have in branch dashboard setting in Android URI Scheme : **testapp://** still i am getting this error.

specified in Branch dashboard doesn't match with the deep link intent in manifest file.

Note : Keys i have checked and it is correct.

Comment: Can you share your complete Manifest file? Also, in the meanwhile pease match your integration as here - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#section-configure-app

Comment: Now it is working. android:host="open" was missing. Don't know why it has not been mentioned in the docs here https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, even after following the above, it did not work even after double verifying everyone.  However, it worked after:

`flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was not to have `://` in android scheme.

```
android:scheme="myappname"
```